# How to Calculate the Page Resolution?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I having a problem with Table format. The MainPage height and width have change into 1024 X 760. Every ROW and COLLUMN is divided properlly and have extra space too but when i Debug the program, The page seem like half page covered by "Something" invisible.

```
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="700"
           Title="ConsultationPage Page" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <sdk:Label Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblCTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Content="Consultation Hour" Margin="12,0,0,0" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="508,14,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="427,14,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
        <Grid x:Name="TableLayoutRoot" Margin="-1,70,0,-70">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40">
                </RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="20">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblMonday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24"  Foreground="#B4000000" Content="Monday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
            <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblTuesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Content="Tuesday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
            <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblWednesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Content="Wednesday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
            <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblThursday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Content="Thursday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
            <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblFriday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Content="Friday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="50,0,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: You're cramming labels with `Height` set to 38 into grid rows with `Height` set at 20, and what's with your strangely large `Margin` settings on everything?

Comment: Maybe you can try and give us an idea of what you're trying to do with your XAML and we can help you get there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw out some XAML for you to try and see if it helps you out, because I'm still not quite sure what you're after with your question.  Try using this layout XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="28" />
        <RowDefinition Height="23" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="lblCTitle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="Consultation Hour" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Grid x:Name="TableLayoutRoot" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lblMonday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24"  Foreground="#B4000000" Text="Monday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lblTuesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Text="Tuesday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lblWednesday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Text="Wednesday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lblThursday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Text="Thursday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="lblFriday" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="24" Foreground="#B4000000" Text="Friday" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I just want to point out a couple of things here.  First off, it looks like you're trying to use `Margin` to do positioning on your controls.  This is not the way to do things in XAML-based layout with Silverlight or WPF.  Use the `<Grid>`, or learn to use `<StackPanel>` or even `<DockingPanel>` - you'll find that each of these suits certain purposes for layout, and often a combination of them is the best fit to get you the layout you need.  Another thing you'll likely want to do that I haven't done here is to use a `StaticResource` or a `Style` for your font size, color, and family - doing so will allow you to change these settings in one place instead of many (five in this case).

Comment: Cool, I'm glad.  Usually here on SO when you like an answer you upvote it using the arrow buttons or accept it using the checkmark.  Glad I was able to help you out.